# Anonymous implementation of an interface method in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, functional-interface

In java, you can use implementations of interfaces like this:

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Filter {
    Query apply(Query query);
}
```

```java
public class FlagFilterFactory {
  public Filter create(SearchQuery searchQuery) {
    return q -> {
      q.addCriteria(...)
      return q;
    };
  }
```

But I did not find how it can be written using Kotlin.

```kotlin
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Filter {
    fun apply(query: Query): Query
}
```

How can one write an anonymous implementation of this interface? Or do I definitely need to create a class in Kotlin that will implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [`fun interface`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) in Kotlin (no pun intended)

```
fun interface Filter {
    fun apply(query: Query): Query
}
```

Usage:

```
fun create(searchQuery: SearchQuery) =
    Filter { q ->
        q.addCriteria(...)
    }
```

Alternatively, don't declare a new type at all, and just use the [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types) `(Query) -> Query`. (You can make a type alias for this)

```
typealias Filter = (Query) -> Query

fun create(searchQuery: SearchQuery): Filter = { q ->
    q.addCriteria(...)
}
```